# Find the UMVUE of $b^{\mu}$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

Let $X_1,X_2,..X_n$ be a random sample from Cauchy$(\mu,1)$ population.
Find the UMVUE of $b^{\mu}$ where $b$ is any positive real number.
Now actually calculating sample mean won't work here because its distribution is also Cauchy$(\mu,1)$,so expectation won't exist.And all I know is that the sample median asymptotically goes to $\mu$,so it won't work here either.Is there any trick other than the normal procedures like Lehmann Scheffe to do this?

Comment: What is $u$? The sample mean $\frac1n \sum X_i$?

Comment: Are you sure about the statement of this exercise?